# Mysql_query insert into

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this insert into mysql query. If I perform it on localhost, everything works fine. However, on my webserver it doesn't want to work, and I don't know why. I tried to change the syntax in many ways though.

```
<?

if( $_POST )
{
 $dbhost ='ip address';
 $dbuser = 'username';
 $dbpassword = 'password';
 $database = 'db1214492_davidmszabo';

 $con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database, $con);


 $users_name = $_POST['name'];
 $users_email = $_POST['email'];
 $users_website = $_POST['website'];
 $users_comment = $_POST['comment'];

 $users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($users_name);
 $users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($users_email);
 $users_website = mysql_real_escape_string($users_website);
 $users_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($users_comment);


 $articleid = $_GET['id'];


if( !is_numeric($articleid) )
die('invalid article id');

      $query = "
  INSERT INTO `db1214492_davidmszabo`.`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `website`,
    `comment`, `timestamp`, `articleid`) VALUES (NULL, '$users_name',        '$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$articleid');";

/* INSERT INTO `inmoti6_mysite`.`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `website`,
    `comment`, `timestamp`, `articleid`) VALUES (NULL, '$users_name',
    '$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$articleid');";*/

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `db1214492_davidmszabo`.`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`,      `website`, `comment`, `timestamp`,
  `articleid`) 
 VALUES (NULL , '$users_name', '$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment',      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$articleid')";

 /*    $sqlTwo = 'INSERT INTO `db1214492_davidmszabo`.`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`,     `website`, `comment`, `timestamp`,
  `articleid`) VALUES (\'\', \'cd\', \'ddsa@enauk.com\', \'dda.com\', \'dsaf\',     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \'1\');'; -  this is the code copied from the phpmyadmin when I insert something in the database */

 mysql_query($query);

 echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";

  mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

// Edited post - And I don't try connecting to localhost. I got an IP address at the $dbhost = "" - 
This is the error I got by adding the two more: lines error_reporting(E_ALL); and
ini_set('display_errors', 1); - and changed the connection to mysqli_connect();

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 105 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 105 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 106 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 106 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 107 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 107 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 108 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 108 Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 155 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 155

and then after my comment:

### Thank you for your comment

the error is this:

Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/479307/webspace/httpdocs/davidmszabo.com/articles/manage_comments.php on line 165

Comment: Does mysql_connect sucess?

Comment: `mysql_connect` is outdated.  You should look into updating to MySQLi/PDO.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not the error you get, nor a detailed description of what is wrong. Please put some effort in describing the situation, instead of just dumping your code.

Comment: Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: Since you haven't even bothered trying to check the return value from `mysql_query()` and are obvious simply assuming everything will always work and never blow up.... perhaps you should start actually checking for failure: `$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` will TELL you why it failed.

Comment: ...in addition, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Nicco - I changed it now to mysqli_connect(); - I think the previous one succeeded as well, because I got the <h2>Thank you for your comment</h2> written on my page.

Comment: @Fred -ii - I added the code and got some nice errors, I didn't know how to do it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of the table you are INSERTing into? If the `id` column is `AUTO_INCREMENT` - you should **not** be trying to insert it.

Also, I'm not sure if `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a valid value (especially if the column is a `DATETIME` type). Perhaps a more experienced MySQL guru can correct me. I always use `NOW()` instead

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `$database`.`comments` (`name`, `email`, `website`, `comment`, `timestamp`, `articleid`) 
        VALUES ('$users_name', '$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment', NOW(), '$articleid')";
```